# tweepy get_user does not work with a list of user_ids

Tags: python, api, tweepy

I am using tweepy library to pull informations about Twitter users. What I want is, given a list of Twitter ids, get the number of followers of each user that relates to the ids. The function looks like this.

```
infos = api.get_user(user_id=xxx)
return infos.followers_count
```

In the Twitter documentation, it says I can input a list of up to 100 user ids to get_user. Thing is, whatever I pass to that function other than a single id, I get the error

```
[{'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist', 'code': 34}]
```

For example if I write:

```
infos = api.get_user(user_id=[user1,user2,user3])
```

I get the error. But if I write

```
infos = api.get_user(user_id=user1)
```

It works perfectly well. Did you encounter this problem before? Is the problem in Tweepy library? Should I use another library?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the function **lookup_users** for this, and the parameter is **user_ids**:

```
infos = api.lookup_users(user_ids=[user1,user2,user3])
```

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L154